# RegExp: Different results when using Backreference

Tags: javascript, regex

See http://jsfiddle.net/aEEUN/

why when I use backreference vs no backrefences, I get different results?

```
var str = "Hello World\nHello          ";
document.write("Without backreference: <br />");
var match = str.match(/\S(?![\s\S]*\S)/);
document.write("- match.index: " + match.index + "<br />"); // index is 16 

document.write("With backreference: <br />");
var match = str.match(/(\S)(?![\s\S]*\1)/);
document.write("- match.index: " + match.index); // index is 6
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is that you constrain the two character to be exactly the same.

In the first regular expression there must not be *any* non-whitespace character following:

```
/\S(?![\s\S]*\S)/
```

This basically means to match any non-whitespace character that is not followed by any other non-whitespace character. That’s why it matches the last `o` that is only followed by whitespace:

```
"Hello World\nHello          "
                  ^ no other non-whitespace character following
```

But in the second regular expression there must not be that *specific* character following that was matched before:

```
/(\S)(?![\s\S]*\1)/
```

This basically means to match any non-whitespace character that does not appear again in the rest of the string. That’s why the `W` is matched as it’s the first non-whitespace character that does not appear again after the first occurrence:

```
"Hello World\nHello          "
       ^ no other “W” following
```

That’s why it’s called a backreference: You reference a previously matched string.

Answer (score 0):

That is some weird regex. The character class `[\s\S]` matches everything doesn't it? A space or non-space? Not sure exactly, but the `\1` in the latter example has to refer to the same character that it did at the start (not just any non-space again)... which would give it a different result.